# How to get a running balance?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm messing around with Google Sheets today, and I'm trying to put together a balance sheet similar to the one my bank uses. Its got both a credit and debit field in each row and a running balance to the far right. I'm kinda new to this, so I'm learning as I go.

I've got it set up like so - cell E2 has the following formula:

```
=sum(c2:d2)
```

While cells E3 and beyond have:

```
=(C4*-1)+D4+E3
```

[image]

It works for the most part, but if you'll notice cells E6 onwards each have the same value as a result of the formula being applied to every cell in that column. Is there any way to hide the balance value or change it to 0 if the debit/credit field is empty, just for layout purposes?

edit:
It's supposed to be a running balance of an account. So the end result is like this

```
DEBIT     CREDIT     BALANCE     DATE
          5          5           05 Feb 2015
1                    4           06 Feb 2015
          10         14          07 Feb 2015
8                    6           09 Feb 2015
```

But just to re-iterate, my issue isn't so much with the formula but rather with the way it displays the total.

I'm looking for something like this (I zeroed out E5-E11 by hand):
[image]

The balance should display "P0.00", or be blank, when the line is empty.

Comment: I don't really understand what the formula is supposed to calculate. Your function subtracts the value in the *Debit* column, but the result in the *Balance* column has added it. How should it be?

Comment: The "Balance" field at the end of each row is supposed to display the new balance after the debit/credit has been added to it. I'll edit my post to show what I'm trying to get.

I do need to change that screenshot though, there was an error in the formula used in that shot, and I've since changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use this formula in `E3` and copy down:

```
=IF(AND(E2<>"",OR(C3<>"",D3<>"")),E2-C3+D3,"")
```

**EXPLANATION:**
The [`IF` statement](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) contains 3 comma separated parameters:

1. logical_expression
2. value_if_true
3. value_if_false

In this case the logical expression is `AND(E2<>"",OR(C3<>"",D3<>""))`.
`AND` takes multiple logical expressions as comma separated parameters, and returns `TRUE` only if all expressions are true. In this case these two:

1. `E2<>""`
2. `OR(C3<>"",D3<>"")`

Number one checks if there is anything in the cell above (if it's not equal to nothing).
Number two is an `OR` function, works as `AND` but returns `TRUE` if only one or more of the expressions are true. In this case:

1. `C3` (the *Debit* value on this row) is not empty
2. `D3` (the *Credit* value on this row) is not empty

So to summarize
If the cell above has a value, and `Debit` or `Credit` has a value. The `value_if_true` is used. In the example: `E2-C3+D3` (the cell above minus `Debit` plus `Credit`).

If the expression evaluates to false, the `value_if_false` is used, in this case `""` (an empty string).

Comment: That worked great, thanks a bunch!